# Drag and drop to reorder rectangles in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

Is it possible to use drag and drop to reorder HTML canvas rectangles, and what is the best way to go about this? Given a bunch of rectangles, I want to be able to change their order by dragging. Or is it easier to achieve this using divs instead? I want to create a rectangle packing program with drag and drop capabilities similar to [Packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/) except implementing a different rectangle packing algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to change order by dragging rectangles is by implementing these plugins like Packery,Gridster,ShapeShift rather than using divs instead.
Gridster cannot be used for multiple layouts whereas Shapeshift comes to the rescue. Comparing these two, Shapeshift is responsive.I suggest to implement any one of these according to their requirement and their frequency of usage.